# Move from view controller to tab bar controller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios5, uitabbarcontroller

When you create a tab bar controller via the interface and not programatically you dont have a tab bar controller class. How do you move from a view controller to this tab bar controller in a case such as this?

Comment: I don't quite get the question... You want to know how to access tab bar controller from its child view controller's code?

Comment: No. I have a view controller that appears before the tab bar controller appears. so basically the ideal program structure i want is view controller -> view controller -> tabbarcontroller (which has two child view controllers)

Comment: And you're showing your view controllers in a navigation controller?

Comment: Nope. Its just a view controller. Basically what i want is a splash screen which is a view controller which modally presents anotehr view controller which finds the current location and when clicked on a button in this view controller the tab bar controller should appear with which has a list view controller and map view controller. Im not sure this is accepted practice though? - Could however use a navigation controller for the two view controllers but i read not to embed a tab bar controller within a nav controller

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted to point out. How about instantiating the tab bar controller and showing the splash screen modally (e.g. without animations, so that user won't notice the tab controller)? Then off that splash screen you present location selector, and when user is done with it you dismiss both modal controllers revealing the tab controller.

Comment: Right that sounds good. Il do that but one question. If i set the current location using the second modal view controller by initialising both the view controllers within the tab controller (vc1, vc2) will this information be passed on when the tab bar shows up eventually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try and create the tab bar controller first. Then show the full-screen splash screen modally (e.g. without animation, so that user won't notice the tab bar controller) and off that splash screen you present location selector. Once the user is done with it you dismiss both modal controllers revealing tab controller.

If you need to set up view controllers in your tab bar controller based on the information you're getting from location selector you can do it e.g. via a delegate, that is:

1. Implement delegate for splash screen and location selector
2. Instantiate tab bar controller
3. Show the splash screen, setting current vc of tab bar controller a delegate of the splash screen
4. Show location selector, setting its delegate to the same view controller (you'll have the handle in splash screen)
5. Once user dismisses location selector you inform the delegate about it and it's able to collect needed data from the location selector.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

At first make the tabbarcontroller then make uiview controller ...such as...

```
NSMutableArray *listOfViewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        tab1view = [[tab1viewcontroller alloc] initWithNibName:@"tab1viewcontroller" bundle:nil];
        [listOfViewControllers tab1view];
        [tab1view release];

        tab2view = [[tab2viewcontroller alloc] initWithNibName:@"tab2viewcontroller" bundle:nil];
        [listOfViewControllers tab2view];
        [tab2view release];

        [self.tabBarController setViewControllers:listOfViewControllers animated:YES];
```

i think it will help you.